# how do i show multiple image in another page using session

Tags: php

```html
<?php
lets have a look in my code i am uploading multiple images using form action
here i am uploading multiple images
Session_Start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 
 


   $upload_path = "/var/www/html/addtocart/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

                           $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
                           $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
                           $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable
                           $target_path = $upload_path . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);//set the target path with a new name of image
         
 

                      $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       
if (file_exists($target_path)) { 
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}      

else { 
if(($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] <50000000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions))
 {

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j.') .<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
               
$File_Name=  basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
     echo $File_Name. "</br>"; 

       
    
$var_holding_img = "<img src='$File_Name' alt='picture' width='200' height='256'><br/>"; 
$string =   $var_holding_img ; //here i want to store multiple images and show all the images in another page
$_SESSION['File_Name'] = $string;
echo $_SESSION['File_Name'] ; 
  






            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>'; 
        }

}
 

    }

echo '<script type="text/javascript">        
      
function Link1()      
{      
if(document.Form1.checkbox1.checked == true)       
{      
alert("Want to Add Some More Medicines.");  
 location.href="products.php"; 
}      
}      
function Link2()      
{      
if(document.Form1.checkbox2.checked == true)       
{      
alert("You have clicked on Make Delivery At Home.");  
location.href="billing.php";      
}      
} 
       
</script>';


  

echo "<form name='Form1' style='color: green ; font-size: 150%' action = '#'> 
 <input type='radio' name='checkbox1' value='' onclick = 'Link1()'  />Want to Add Some More Medicines<br>
 <input type='radio' name='checkbox2' value='' onclick = 'Link2()'  />Make Delivery At Home<br>
</form>";



}
```

Comment: help me out with this code

Comment: Have you started session on both pages?

Comment: yes i had started seesion in both pages

Comment: Can you show a bit more complete code then? All the relevant including the session_start command for example?

Comment: it is working but it is showing only one image but i had uploaded multiple image

Comment: Where in your code are you storing more than one item in that session value? You are just assigning one value. So it can't echo anything else.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$_SESSION['File_Name']` should be array.
2. You need to `session_start ();` on both pages.
3. To show all images on second page you need to iterate trough array in loop and generate html the way you want for your result to show up...

**example**:
I don't know from your code how do you get links for your images (from DB or scrap them from 1st page with JS or get them from file or go trough directory...) so I'll assume you have `$_SESSION['fileNames'] = ['src1','src2','src3'];`

Then I would do something like this:

```
$imgSrcArray = $_SESSION['fileNames'];
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($imgSrcArray as $src) {
    echo '<li><img src="'.$src.'"/></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Of course, adjust html as it suites you.

**Second edit**:
Check this one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php and then populate session array with file names of your images. Then change code above like this `echo '<li><img src=HERE_GOES_PATH_TO_YOUR_FOLDER/"'.$src.'"/></li>';`

Comment: @RohitJha, I've edited my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: here it is not working dude i am uploading my whole page plze have a look

Comment: i had uploaded whole page plze had a look